# Cannot match specific group in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, capture-group, rainbow-js

- [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jA3aK9/5)
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne8cpngb/3)

I'm using the [Rainbow.js](http://craig.is/making/rainbows) library to add syntax highlighting to LaTeX code like so:

```
Rainbow.extend('latex', [
    {
        'name': 'comment',
        'pattern': /%.*$/gm
    },
    {
        'name': 'storage.function',
        'pattern': /\\[A-z@]+/g
    },
    {
        'matches':
        {
            1: 'entity.name.function',
            3: 'entity.class'
        },
        'pattern': /(\\(begin|end))\s*\{(.*?)\}/g
    }
], true)
```

but it fails to highlight group `#3` even though—by everything I see otherwise—the group is being captured.  Any idea what may be going wrong?  Why would it match the first group but not the third?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you tried using non-capturing groups for the groups that don't need capturing? E.g. `(\\(?:begin|end))` (and then I guess you need `matches: {1: ..., 2: ...}` or `matches: {0: ..., 1: ...}`).

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for that! I'm still *very* new to JavaScript and extended regex in general.  Shouldn't have an impact though, yes?

Comment: `[A-z]` is possibly an invalid range (it is case-sensitive): You need `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @FelixKling O.O So adding that change did fix the issue.  Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @OnlineCop Thanks for the tip, fixed!

Comment: Well, since I'm not familiar with Rainbow.js, I'd rather have someone write an answer who can explain why that fixes it.

Comment: `[A-z]` is valid, but captures a bit more than letters (e.g. square brackets). And @FelixKling is right, rainbow apparently only colours sequential `matches`, and stops when it gets `undefined` for `2`.

Comment: @FelixKling Definitely fair. I'm curious myself… **Edit** I had actually figured as much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you forgot to escape a second bracket so it would be `/(\\(begin|end\\))\s*\{(.*?)\}/g`.

But you will only have two groups the first `(\\(begin|end\\))` and the second `(.*)`.
If you don't need to get the content of a group you can make it non-capturing (it will improve the performance by the way) see [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group).

For the `A-z` range it doesn't work like `a-zA-Z` see [character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). You should rather use a `a-z` range with the flag `i` which means you ignore case.